# さくらのVPSのVNCコンソールにioremap errorが出る

Tags: ssh, さくらインターネット

さくらのVPSにubuntuサーバーを構築して運用しております。

これまでは問題なくログインできていました。
ただ、容量不足のため
`sudo reboot`コマンドでしてサーバーを再起動し、
32GBにスケールアップしました。
するとsshログインできなくなり、さくらのVNCコンソールには以下のようなエラーが出てフリーズしています。
[image: VNCコンソール]

sshログインしようとすると以下のエラーがでます。
`port 22: Operation timed out`
どのように解決できるでしょうか。
解決のために足りない情報などございましたらご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: sshで接続できないのは恐らくOSの正常起動が完了していないからで、VNCコンソールに表示されている「`ioremap error`」を主題にした質問とした方が伝わりやすいと思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問のタイトルと内容を変更してみました。